# How bad is my runaway fission reaction?

Tags: internal-consistency, physics

During WWII in an alternate universe, the nuclear bomb is being developed. Interestingly, radiation amounts are far higher than predicted when enriched. Unbeknownst to the scientists, highly enriched nuclear material and fission on scales such as nuclear weapon produces large amounts of strange particles known as delta rays. Delta rays went unnoticed, as they were near imperceptible on small fission scales. Delta rays induce fission in any unstable element that they impacts, creating increased levels of beta and gamma radiation than predicted. Testing continues as normal, and the Trinity test is carried out. Suddenly, the yield is more like 1 megaton as opposed to the mere 11.2 kiloton yield that occurred in our universe due to the runaway reaction of delta rays with the unstable elements that were present in the air, ground, etc. Is this feasible? How can I prevent the delta rays from using up all accessible unstable elements on the planet through a runaway reaction?

Comment: There aren't so much unstable elements in air or ground to account for 1000x yield, unless you suggest that chain reaction would travel away from the test site. In that case entire Earth would be involved in that reaction.

Comment: Should I tone it down?

Comment: If you want to stick with this scientific explanation and don't invent more, then yes.

Comment: I will say that only about 1-10% of the yield from hiroshima actually exploded, the rest was blown away, so 10-100x yield will be feasible.

Comment: @Salami-tsunami the accepted figure for hiroshima bomb is 1.7%. Better with the others, that used plutonium, but still under 3%

Answer (score 4):

**Fission that yields energy only occurs with elements heavier than iron.
But maybe you could have delta rays catalyze fusion.**

As written your delta rays catalyze fission.  It is not unstable elements that undergo fission.  It is heavy elements.

https://www.physlink.com/education/askexperts/ae659.cfm

> Why is uranium fissionable and not, say, aluminum? Asked by: Bill
>
> Answer The short answer is "aluminum's not big enough." Here's why:
> The nuclear force saturates due to its short range, meaning that
> heavier nuclei have protons that don't attract each other via the
> nuclear force but still repel each other electrostatically. This is
> why heavier nuclei tend to have more neutrons in relation to the
> number of protons - the neutrons only attract. The binding energy per
> nucleon, a measure of how tightly a nucleus is bound, peaks at about
> 60 nucleons. (There's also a sharp peak at 4; the alpha particle,
> which is a He-4 nucleus, is very tightly bound) So light nuclei
> require energy to split apart and would release energy only if you can
> fuse them together. You might expect that anything heavier than 120
> nucleons would fission, but these nuclei are still bound together, so
> the two parts you would get in fission aren't likely to fly apart.
> It's not until you get into the elements heavier than lead (all of
> which are radioactive) that you find nuclei whose binding energy per
> nucleon is low enough that the fission fragments could tunnel apart.
> Answered by: Tom Swanson, Ph.D., Physicist, US Naval Observatory

Elements heavier than iron are not commonly just lying around.  There might be a little copper or arsenic in the soil.   However, the people conducting the test may have brought in a lot of elements heavier than iron.  Specifically lead, used to shield equipment and viewers.  There might be a lot of that.

If you wanted to have your delta rays catalyze fusion, that would release a lot of energy the way you want.  There are lots of light elements on the surface which could undergo fusion.  If fission produces delta rays that catalyze fusion, that would make your big kaboom but not an actual earthshattering kaboom.  Since fusion does not make the rays, the reaction would not be self sustaining.  This would also provide a real world identity for delta rays - they are high velocity muons, and they are producing [muon-catalyzed fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon-catalyzed_fusion)

Comment: This is true only for stable isotopes. Unstable isotopes of any element, however light, decay on their own and produce energy. For example, Carbon 14 decays to Nitrogen 14 - but there's only 1 atom of Carbon 14 for trillion of other Carbon atoms.

Comment: @Alexander - the energy produced by radioactive decay can be made to do work, but it is chump change compared to that which is possible with fusion or fission.

Answer (score 1):

## Feasible. (but scary)

With the single edit that these delta rays not only ease fission but they (or another emission) also ease *fusion*.

During the development of the nuclear bomb, the scientists under Oppenheimer were concerned about the possibility that the temperatures created by the fission bomb might be enough to initiate *fusion* in the hydrogen on Earth. They were sufficiently worried about it that they sent considerable time calculating the effect, before accepting that the temperature and density simply were not enough to initiate this sort of runaway reaction.

But!  If there is a secondary effect in the fission bomb that eases additional fission and fusion, then that is a totally different matter.

As for the scale: If the Little Boy bomb (hiroshima) , using the same components as on our Earth, generated a 1Mt explosion... Yes, that is quite believable. ***ALL*** it requires is that the entirety of the fissile material in the bomb get used up, instead of the 1.7% that fissioned in Little Boy. (if you want to be pedantic, the yield would be 880Kt, not 1 Mt)

Now for your question: :"How can I prevent the delta rays from using up all accessible unstable elements on the planet through a runaway reaction?"

You...............cannot.
byebye.
End-of-world music start playing, please.
.
.
.

Oh. You really want a way out of this?
Um... handwavium, erm, technobabble doubletalk, hmm, McGuffin...

## AHA!

Make your Delta Rays be a particle that decays very, very^very quickly. Meaning it only has an effect out to a certain radius from the initiating point, before it decomposes into something else that is more harmless. Say the particle decays in under half a nanosecond. That will give it (with relativity giving a helping hand), a range of about 500 meters.

Thus, the *intense* burst of Delta is enough to trigger fission/fusion in nearby elements in the ground. But *those* fissions are diffuse enough that the Delta wavefront they propagate is much less concentrated, resulting in much less induced fission/fusion in adjoining material. Pretty soon, it tapers off to nothing.

Unless.. You detonate a nuclear bomb near another bomb. Or near a nuclear reactor. Or on that mountain range that has a really rich Pitchblende ore in it!

Comment: A light nano-second is exactly 29.9792458 cm. So your particles would have to travel at 0.999999999992c to travel 500 meters. That's a lot of help from relativity :-) Faster than the particles in the large hadron collider.